# Is restricting identifiers to alphanumeric words enough to prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I need to use dynamic table names which can't be provided as parameters in prepared statements. I figured that if I restrict identifier names to alphanumeric + underscore only, then there is no way some sql could be injected, right?

here's the check function:

```
function is_safe_identifier($s) {
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $s) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't you know the allowed column names beforehand? So, whitelist them.

Comment: TL;DR on the dupe: NO, it's not enough. What you should do is whitelist the parts you can't prepare. In other words, make a list of tables and ensure it's part of that list

Comment: There's little change of SQL injection if they cannot be provided as parameters in prepared statements. ;-) To be honest, I think this will do the trick,  though many people would like to see even more protection. Make sure you **bind** the parameters.

Comment: You could make a prepared statement which checks the table name against the catalog

Comment: @Machavity why not? what combination of the allowed characters could possibly inject SQL?

Comment: @user81993 Because you can figure out your DB structure via [trial and error](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Server#Trial_and_error). You should expose as little of your application as you can

Comment: @Machavity the structure is not a secret though and a whitelist wouldn't do anything against that anyways